# The connection between the Riemann hypothesis and the harmonic series

Tags: riemann-hypothesis

I have heard most people say that the harmonic series, given by
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^{-1}}$, is central or somehow related to a proof of the Riemann hypothesis. I have been trying to understand the sense in which such an assertion is held but to no avail. If anybody could enlighten me about this connection I would be grateful.

Comment: Note: the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$ is the (divergent) harmonic series

Comment: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/elementaryrh.pdf

Comment: Well, the Riemann hypothesis is an assertion about the so-called "nontrivial" zeros of the Riemann zeta function $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^s}.$$ Although the above definitions is for $\text{Re }(s)>1$, one could claim that $$\zeta(1)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1n $$ which actually works in the sense that $\zeta(s)$ by definition diverges at $s=1$. Other than the relation between the divergent harmonic series and $\zeta(s)$, there is probably little connection to the Riemann hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

- The asymptotic of $\sum_{n \le x} \frac1n$ as $x \to \infty$ is easily found with some $x^{-10}$ error term.
- The PNT and the Riemann hypothesis (more generally the analytic continuation of $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)},\log \zeta(s),\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$) is about the asymptotic of $\prod_{p \le x} \frac{1}{1-p^{-1}} = \sum_{n, \text{Lpf}(n) \le x} \frac1n$ where $\text{Lpf}$ is the largest prime factor.

Comment: What do you not understand in my answer ?  Depending on the order of summation, $\sum n^{-s}$ goes from "almost trivial" to "as complicated as the RH"

Answer (score 0):

This paper proves several equivalents of the Riemann hypothesis in terms of the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ and the harmonic numbers $H_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$: [http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/v31/v31.pdf](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/v31/v31.pdf)
For example, the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to
$$\left|\mathbf{p}(e^\gamma n) -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 2}^{n-1}   \frac{1}{H_k}   \right| <  \frac{1}{33} \frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{3}{2n}, \quad \forall n \geq 1,$$
where $\mathbf{p}(x) = \pi(x)/x$.

There's also a famous paper by Lagarias expressing the Riemann hypothesis in terms of the sum of divisors function and the harmonic numbers: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008177

Answer (score -3):

Well the generalized harmonic series, given by 
$$S_{n,2j}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2j}; j\in\mathbb{N}\tag{1},$$ 
is central to a (to be verified) proof of the Riemann hypothesis. See  (Ref.1:[a preprint at arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08868)).

The method used in Ref.1 is based on the approach of Polya and Hurwitz. It is summarized in [a MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297969/sign-unchanged-for-dirichlet-polynomials).

For Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, the Dirichlet character $\chi$ weighted generalized harmonic series appeared. 
$$S_{n,2j}(\chi)=\sum_{k=1}^n \chi(k)k^{2j+b}; b=0,1;j\in\mathbb{N}_0\tag{2}.$$