# sign unchanged for Dirichlet polynomials?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Let $\chi_{q}$ be a primitive Dirichlet character with modulus $q$ [(see definition at wikipedia )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character).
For example for $q=5$ we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\chi_{5,1}&=(1,  1,  1,  1, 0),\\
\chi_{5,2}&=(1,  i, -i, -1, 0),\qquad\qquad \text{(1)}\\
\chi_{5,3}&=(1, -1, -1,  1, 0),\\
\chi_{5,4}&=(1, -i,  i, -1, 0),\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Let $B(\chi_q)=(1/2)(1-\chi_q(-1))$ so $B(\chi_{5,1})=B(\chi_{5,3})=0,B(\chi_{5,2})=B(\chi_{5,4})=1$.

Denote $n\in\mathbb{N},j\in\mathbb{N_0}$ and we construct the Dirichlet polynomials $P(n,j,\chi_{q})$

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(n,j,\chi_{q})&=\sum_{k=1}^{qn}k^{2j+B(\chi_q)}\chi_q(k)\qquad\qquad \text{(2)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**Proposition A:**

$\color{red}{sign(\mathrm{Re}\chi_{q}(-1))}P(n,j,\mathrm{Re}\chi_{q})$ and $\color{red}{sign(\mathrm{Im}\chi_{q}(-2))}P(n,j,\mathrm{Im}\chi_{q})$will remain **nonnegative** for all $n\geq 1, j\geq 0$.

We use Mathematica numerically verified this proposition for $q=5,7;n=1,5;j=0,...,4$ total 20 cases.

We would like to seek references on a proof of **Proposition A**. This proposition showed up when we study the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis for L-functions associated primitive Dirichlet character.

We will now provide some background information behind our motivation for asking this question.  This is related to
**An Interesting Approach** towards proving GRH. For simplicity, we will describe it for odd $\chi$, i.e., $\chi(-1)=-1$.

Let $\Lambda(s,\chi)$ be the Gamma completed L-function $$\Lambda(s,\chi):=(\pi/q)^{-(s+1)/2}\Gamma((s+1)/2)L(s,\chi)\tag{3}$$ 
where $L(s,\chi)$ denotes
the Dirichlet L-function. It satisfies the functional relation 
$$\Lambda(1-s,\bar{\chi})=\frac{i q^{1/2}}{\tau(\chi)}\Lambda(s,\chi).\tag{4}$$

Let $$\Xi(z)
:=\tfrac12\Lambda(\tfrac12+iz,\chi)+\tfrac12\Lambda(\tfrac12-iz,\bar{\chi}),\tag{5}$$

Notice that $\Xi(x)\in\mathbb{R}(x), x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The Generalized Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the statements that

(A) there exists a family of entire function $W_n(z)$ (even in $z$) such that $W_n(z)$ uniformly converges to $\Xi(z)$ in $\{0<\mathrm{Im}z<1/2\}$. Using a corollary
of Hurwitz's theorem in complex analysis we can prove that if all the zeros of $W_n(z)$ are real, then $\Xi(z)$ has no zeros in $\{0<\mathrm{Im} z<1/2\}$;

(B) Find a pair of functions such that $W_n(z)=U_n(z)-V_n(z)$.   $U_n(z),V_n(z)$ are also even in $z$. Prove that all the zeros of $U_n(z),V_n(z)$ are simple and real.

(C) Prove that the positive zeros of $U_n(z)$ are strictly (say) left-interlacing with those of $V_n(z)$. Using an entire function equivalent to Hermite-Kakeya Theorem for
polynomials,  it can be shown that $W_n(z)$ has only real and simple zeros.

This approach appeared in a preprint on arXiv [(Ref.1) On the zeros of Riemann Xi-function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08868)

Adapting the approach of [(Ref.1)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08868), we are able to show that the following family of functions $W_n(n,z)$ satisfies condition in statement (A) above

$$
W_n(n,z):=2\omega_n\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^jc_{j}\tilde{S}_{n,2j+1}(\chi)\mathrm{sinc}[\omega_n (z-i\phi_{j})]\\+2\omega_n\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^jc_{j}\tilde{S}_{n,2j+1}(\bar{\chi})\mathrm{sinc}[\omega_n (z+i\phi_{j})].\tag{6}
$$
where
$$
\omega_n:=\tfrac12\log n,\quad
\phi_{n,j}:=2j+\tfrac32,\tag{7}
$$

$$
c_{j}:=\frac{(\pi/q)^j}{\Gamma(j+1)},\qquad\tilde{S}_{n,2j+1}(\chi)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2j+1}\chi(k)\quad
,\tag{8}\\
$$

**Motivation for OP**: From (8) we can see, for example, that if the Dirichlet polynomials $\tilde{S}_{5n,2j+1}(\mathrm{Re}\chi_{5,2}), \tilde{S}_{5n,2j+1}(\mathrm{Im}\chi_{5,2})$ have fixed signs for all $n,j$, then we can rewrite (6) as $W_n(z)=U_n(z)-V_n(z)$ to partially satisfy the condition of statement (B).

It remains to prove, following [(Ref.1)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08868), that $U_n(z),V_n(z)$ have only real zeros and the positive zeros of $U_n(z)$ are strictly interlacing with those of $V_n(z)$.

**Update**
@GH-from-MO found a counterexample to Proposition A when $q=17,j=0,n=1$. See [a related question that I posted at mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337800/the-sign-of-an-interesting-sum-involving-a-dirichlet-character).  Numerical values showed that When $q=17,4\leqslant j\leqslant 9,n=1$ Proposition A holds.  Thus we suspect that Proposition A holds for $q=17,4=j_0\leqslant j,n=1$ and this $j_0$ should depend on $q$.

Comment: Thanks for the editing!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: For $q=5$, there are 4 $\chi$s, Please see (1) in the main text. I forgot to emphasize that the variables in $P(q,j,\Re\chi_q)P(q,j,\Im\chi_q)$ are $\Re\chi_q,\Im\chi_q$.

Comment: @reuns: I will modify the main text to answer your second question...

Comment: @reuns: your question "why the sign (of the real and imaginary parts) would be useful for" is answered in the main text.

Comment: I found the non-negative or non-positive pattern. So I updated the Proposition A in the main text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an incomplete proof that we came up last night. We will only show the proof for odd $\chi_q$, i.e., $\chi_q(-1)=-1$ and thus $B(\chi_q)=1$. To simplify the notation, we will set $u=\mathrm{Re}\chi_q, v=\mathrm{Im}\chi_q$ and $Q(n,2j+1,u)=sign(u(-1))P(n,j,u)=-P(n,j,u)$.

The goal is to prove $Q(n\geq 1,j\geq 1,u)\geq 0$.

First
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Q(n,j,u)&=-\sum_{k=1}^{qn}k^{j}u(k)\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{q}u(k)\sum_{m=0}^{n}(mq+k)^{j}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^{q}(-1)u(k)(mq+k)^{j}}\\
&=:\sum_{m=0}^{n}\color{red}{F(m,j)},\qquad (1)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Since for $m\geq 1, j\geq 1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}m}F(m,j)
&=jq\sum_{k=1}^{q}(-1)u(k)(mq+k)^{j-1}\\
&=jqF(m,j-1),\qquad (2)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$F(m\geq 1,j\geq 1)$ is nondecresing for $m$ if $F(m\geq 1,j-1)\geq 0$.

Thus it is suffice to prove that $F(m\geq 1,0)\geq 0$ and $F(0,j\geq 0)\geq 0$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F(m,j)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{q}(-1)u(k)(mq+k)^{j}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{q}(-1)u(k)\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}(mq)^l k^{j-l}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}(mq)^l\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^{q}(-1)u(k)k^{j-l}}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}(mq)^l\color{red}{F(0,j-l)},\qquad (3)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thus it is suffice to prove that $F(0,j\geq 0)\geq 0$.

For $j\geq 1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}j}F(0,j)
&=j\sum_{k=1}^{q}(-1)u(k)k^{j-1}\\
&=jF(0,j-1),\qquad (4)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thus it is suffice to prove that $F(0,1)>0$ because
for primitive and non principal character, we know that $F(0,0)=-\mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{q}\chi_q(k)=0$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F(0,1)
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{q}ku(k)\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{q-1}}ku(k)\\
&=-\left[(q-1)u(q-1)+\cdots+2u(2)+1\right]\\
&=q-2-\sum_{k=2}^{\color{red}{q-2}}ku(k)\quad \because u(q-1)=u(-1)=-1,
\qquad (5)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I have no idea how to proceed from here. 
I posted [a new question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337800/sign-of-a-special-dirichlet-polynomial) at mathoverflow for proving $F(0,1)$ in (5) is positive.